# How to get etheric light?

Tags: destiny

How can I get etheric light to upgrade my legendary weapon without buying any DLC or expansion pack in Destiny. Is the only way possible to buy it from the Iron Banner Vanguard guy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the current ways to obtain Etheric Light:

- Nightfall strike reward (one of many possibilities)
- Iron Banner (one can be purchased at rank 3 and another at rank 5)
- Prison of Elders at level 34 (rotating challenge) and level 35 (Skolas) will each reward an Etheric Light
- Trials of Osiris silver, gold, and lighthouse chest contain one each
- If you are rank 2 or higher with the House of Judgement, Variks will give you a random package of goodies once per week, this may contain an Etheric Light starting at rank 3 and up.

Of these, the Prison of Elders challenges are the most consistent, as well as Trials of Osiris if you are good at PvP.

Comment: Variks can also randomly award one in his weekly bonus package if you are rank 4.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, @TravisJ. I'm not rank 4 with House of Judgment on any of my characters.

Comment: should point out that only the first 2 can be obtained without DLC, as that's what the asker wanted as well.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to obtain Etheric Light through **any** means without the expansions, as it is marked as a House of Wolves item. If someone can confirm or deny, I'll edit it in to my answer.

Comment: I remember Bungie specifically noting that the Nightfall (when it isn't a DLC strike) and IB can be used by players who don't own DLC in order to get to level 34.

Comment: @Adeese If you can find an official reference, that would be very useful.

Comment: @Iszi Unfortunately I can't find anything specific. It might have been during the first House of Wolves Twitch reveal, not sure though.